# Receiving syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_when for code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a table Cases with the has_many association to users. I'm trying to display all the cases related to a user by rendering it in user show page. I'm unable to render the case in here. Any help would be appreciated.

My code for user show page :

```
 <table >
  <tr>
    <td >
      <h1>
        Welcome <%= current_user.first_name %>  you are <%= current_user.role %>    
      </h1>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <% render @cases %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Show controller in users:

```
     def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @cases = @user.cases
    @title = @user.first_name
    end
```

I have a file _case.html.erb in views/cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `case` is a reserved word in Ruby, and when do `render @cases`, it is trying to create a local variable called `case` in the partial, which is not allowed. You have to call the local variable something else. The [docs here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) explain how with this example:

> ```
> # Renders a collection of partials but with a custom local variable name
> render :partial => "admin_person", :collection => @winners, :as => :person
> ```

In your case that would be:

```
render :partial => 'case', :collection => @cases, :as => :current_case
```

And then in the case partial, just use the variable `current_case` where you would have otherwise used the variable `case`.

Comment: Do I need to change it even in data base?

Comment: No, you don't have to change anything except this line (and the partial, just use `current_case` where you would have used the local variable `case`).

Comment: (But be aware that calling your model "Case" may result in similar problems in the future)